# Getting type guard like functionality from conditional typed function

Tags: typescript

I've got the following minimal example that makes use of conditional types.

```js
const wrap = <T extends boolean>(val: number, foo: T): T extends true ? {foo: number} : {bar: number} => {
    if (foo) {
        return {foo: val} as any;
    }
    return {bar: val} as any;
}

const test = Math.random() < 0.5;
const val = wrap(21, test);

if (test) {
    console.log(val.foo);
} else {
    console.log(val.bar);
}
```

(In [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA7gJwIYAcYF4YB4AqMCmAHlPmACYQwBGIIANvkmAHwAUAbknQFwxgCuAWyr4EAGhgAzWrxwBKWQWKkKMKAn74YAfhgBvaSF4DhogL4xeeqkgTGhIhBfTN9AWABQMbzACWkmFZDOXcvH3CEfCh+BDB9Q15OOgskSiYATwBuT3CzHJ9I6Nj9GzsYJJS0sCzPPI9PUEhYEmgMGABZJCgACwA6ZHIQQVYQrBgABl6AVmyPRtaktsRUVgAmAEYJFqg5Wc9-QO2QvXzvefp8XroQAHMOLl7g2Yt8OggtE7Cz8AgLq9v7nReqVdrVPEA)).

It throws an error at both of the `console.log` statements:

```
Property 'foo' does not exist on type '{ foo: number; } | { bar: number; }'.
  Property 'foo' does not exist on type '{ bar: number; }'.(2339)
Property 'bar' does not exist on type '{ foo: number; } | { bar: number; }'.
  Property 'bar' does not exist on type '{ foo: number; }'.(2339)
```

However if test is true, the output should only ever be `{foo: number}`, and if it's false, it should only ever be `{bar: number}`.

I am aware that I can use:

```js
if ('foo' in val) {
  console.log(val.foo);
} else {
  console.log(val.bar);
}
```

But that seems to defeat the purpose of the conditional types in the function definition.

I'd like to know if there's a way to discriminate the type using the value input in the function instead of the value returned from the function. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't have a concrete answer, but in your conditional return type, is extending a primitive (true) causing the issue? In most of the examples I have seen, such conditions are used between two different types, i.e. T extends number or string, not the actual value of a particular primitive type as in your example.

Comment: @HarleyThomas Their first example in [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) uses the primitive values like this. This scenario is just an extension of that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say this is a case of TypeScript's lack of support for what I've been calling "correlated union types".  See [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) for a discussion.

The compiler sees the type of `test` as `true | false` (which is displayed as `boolean`, but is treated as the union of the two boolean literal types), and `val` as type `{bar: number} | {foo: number}`:

```
const test = Math.random() < 0.5; // boolean
const val = wrap(21, test); // {bar: number} | {foo: number}
```

These types are not *wrong*, but they are not very helpful for the kind of subsequent testing you are doing.  The compiler sees the types of `test` and `val` as being completely *uncorrelated*; since each variable is a union of two members, the pair `[test, val]` could be considered to be of the four-member union `[true, {foo: number}] | [true, {bar: number}] | [false, {foo: number}] | [false, {bar: number}]` as far as the compiler knows.  Any information about the correlation between `test` and `val` has been discarded by the compiler.  It just does not keep track of this for you.

Indeed, if the compiler attempted to keep track of possible correlations between the types of *every* set of possibly-related variables, its performance would be *catastrophically poor*.

<sup>(TS 4.4 update: this next line is no longer strictly true, although the fix at [microsoft/TypeScript#44730](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/44730) still does not work on multiple correlated variables. <strike>See [microsoft/TypeScript#12184](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12184) for a related request to keep track of such correlations with `boolean` variables, and the reply there is that it would probably be too complex to implement.</strike>)</sup>

At some point I had suggested an "opt in" version of such analysis (see [microsoft/TypeScript#25051](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25051)) where you could tell it that the code block should be analyzed twice, once for each union member of `test`.  But this request was essentially declined.

For now, there just isn't any support for arbitrarily correlated union types.  You will have to work around it.

---

The easiest workaround to the general case of correlated unions is to use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions); the compiler can't tell what type `val` is, so you just tell it:

```
if (test) {
  console.log((val as { foo: number }).foo);
} else {
  console.log((val as { bar: number }).bar);
}
```

The other general solution involves repetition, to force the compiler to walk through the different possibilities via control flow analysis:

```
if (test) {
  const val = wrap(21, test);
  console.log(val.foo);
} else {
  const val = wrap(21, test);
  console.log(val.bar);
}
```

---

Neither of those are satisfying here... it would undoubtedly be better to refactor so that the compiler isn't expected to keep track of the relationship between `test` and `val`.  Like your version:

```
if ("foo" in val) {
  console.log(val.foo);
} else {
  console.log(val.bar);
}
```

Along the same vein, you could refactor `wrap()` so that its output is a true [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) where `test` is actually stored in the output:

```
const discrimWrap = <T extends boolean>(val: number, test: T): (
  T extends true ? { test: T, foo: number } : { test: T, bar: number }) => {
  if (test) {
    return { test, foo: val, } as any;
  }
  return { test, bar: val } as any;
}
```

Now instead of caring about the variable named `test`, you can use the `test` property of the wrapped output:

```
const discrimVal = discrimWrap(12, test);
if (discrimVal.test) {
  console.log(discrimVal.foo);
} else {
  console.log(discrimVal.bar);
}
```

Discriminated unions are one of the few places in TypeScript where it actually attempts to keep track of correlations.  But they only work in specific circumstances, where the discriminant is a property of the object (and not a separate variable) and where it is a "singleton" or literal type (and not a wide type like `string` or `number`).  And so **this would be the refactoring I'd suggest here**.

---

Finally, I would say that the "purpose of the conditional types in the function definition", as intended by the language designers, is *not* to be used to discriminate a `test` of a *union* type like `boolean`.  When you pass a union in, a union comes out.

The purpose is to narrow the result type if the second argument is known by the compiler to be `true` or `false` via control flow analysis:

```
wrap(21, true).foo; // okay
wrap(21, false).bar; // okay
test ? wrap(21, test).foo : wrap(21, test).bar; // okay
```

That last line works because the compiler can *narrow* `test` to `true` and to `false` in each of the last two operands of the ternary expression, respectively.  But if you call `wrap(21, test)` in a context where `test` is only known to be `boolean`, then the compiler loses any correlation.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA7gJwIYAcYF4YB4AqMCmAHlPmACYQwBGIIANvkmAHwAUAbknQFwxgCuAWyr4EAGhgAzWrxwBKWQWKkKMKAn74YAfhgBvKTL5CRCGAF8YvA1SQJeA4aIsZm+gFAwYAS0kxW0iByHl5eCPhQ-Ahg+oYgvJx0LkiUTACeANyeFtnhkdGxtvYwicmpYJnu5u7uoJCwJNAYMACySFAAFgB0yOQggqzBWDAADF0ArBkwAPTT1LQMTLXgTaWYiKisAEwAjBKNUHJTs-pFDiailgA++oHnTgjV7hso23tqGvhyXYHHcyAAayQaWeyFeuwkki4EC+XSKfxggOB7gOOngYLe+3w0G+gSs6M2ELU2MOcLsCKRIPcvn8B2CemydQg9HwXToIAA5qwOFwYClYndjA8LLjaEcqgQ6DCQjAmSy2ZzuaV+TY7PdTCKyQhxU9qX5WHSZUzYGsCeD3nSsl45QwFVzEj8xVlLPgpVoGdaVibeesMUTLYyVvL2fauFqdTUaawAESBaM+GKJemByDBxUOwI6yXSj2yoO2kM8ujh501Y0wMjeCDABDeQQAdTBzVwShI5EoNBZTDYiXVoix0FkCn82TwRDbqnUmjRBgOskhRkcGss1mJg5gOAkZyFy+C6DcuajhtzYQiURis5JC-iJS4Eks-PSVpyp-yF7XUC3atvSQf5UqTzlpW1a1oIABqPoVlWNZ1o2mw7FsA6HFkUbATB4FhseKbMgWipoaBEHFpmEqujm2Fply+F1oR4ZVEAA)

Answer (score 0):

Does this implementation solve your issue?

```
function wrap(val: number, foo: true): { foo: number }
function wrap(val: number, foo: false): { bar: number }
function wrap(val: number, foo: boolean): { foo: number } | { bar: number } {
    if (foo) return { foo: val }
    if (bar) return { bar: val }
}
```

When calling,

```
wrap(2, true)  // returns { foo: 2 }
wrap(2, false) // returns { bar: 2 }
```